# Change SESSION variable value

Tags: php, forms, session

I've been attempting to figure this out for a little while now, and it's driving me nuts.  Basically I have a form for US and Canadian users.  There's a link at the bottom of the form for Canadian users, which directs users to can-sesssion.php, which contains:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['can'])) {
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    session_unset();
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['can'] = 2;
}
else {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['can'] = 1;
}
header('Location: '. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . '');
?>
```

Basically, if they click on the link, it sets $_SESSION['can'] = 1.  Now There's another option, and if they click that link, it takes them back to this page, and the session should be destroyed and a new value is set (well, that's what it's supposed to do).  Problem is, I've printed out $_SESSION['can'], and it's still retaining that old value after going to that page.  Is there a better way to do this, or is there something wrong w/ my code?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should be aware that the `HTTP_REFERER` is not a header you can rely on being set, or being set to the actual referring page. It is optional and the browser can send whatever it wants.

Comment: Is there an option that would be more useful, or would it be more pragmatic to simply include this php within the page?

Comment: You put the code wherever you want to change the session variable. You can change things as many times as you need without sending anyone to a new page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what you wrote:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['can'])) {
    session_start();
```

`session_start` is the function which reads the session file associated with the user's `PHPSESSID` cookie and populates `$_SESSION`, so you're trying to read from the array before it has any values.

You need to call `session_start` *before* you check if `$_SESSION['can']` has a value.

You also do not need to destroy and create a new session just to change a value.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['can'])) {
    $_SESSION['can'] = 2;
} else {
    $_SESSION['can'] = 1;
}
header('Location: '. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . '');
?>
```

Comment: Gotcha.  Yea, I was just destroying the session as another last ditch effort, but obviously it wouldn't have worked since I didn't initialize the session in the first place.

Comment: I'm showing the other response came up first on my end.  I appreciate your quick response though.

Comment: Here's what shows on my end: answered 25 mins ago - Neal ----- answered 27 mins ago - Dan

Comment: Wow, sorry bud, my mind wasn't there for a minute.  Fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: (using only **one** `session_start()`)

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['can'])) {
    $_SESSION['can'] = 2;
}
else {
    $_SESSION['can'] = 1;
}
header('Location: '. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . '');
?>
```

Comment: Perfecto!  Any idea why the multiple session_start()'s were breaking it?

Comment: they weren't, you were just calling it at the **wrong** time ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You may want to include

```php
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
  session_start();
}
```

instead of just plain

```
session_start();
```